# Given the area, find the maximum upper bound of a definite integral for a continuous, positive one-variable function

Tags: calculus, integration

Being given the area $S>0$, maximize the upper bound of a definite integral $\tau>0$ of a continuous, differentiable, one-variable function $f(t)$.

$$ \int_{0}^\tau f(t)\,dt=S.$$

Assume that the function $f(t)$ satisfies the following properties:

1) $f(0)=a$, where $a>0$ and is a given constant;

2) $f(t)>0$ for $t \in [0,\tau)$;

3) $f(\tau)=0$.

EDIT: differentiable.

Comment: @user357980 I really don't know how to start. I have solved it for linear and exponential functions. I am wondering if there are some known methods of solving such problems.

Comment: Try piece-wise linear functions.

I also am not sure what the problem is asking. It seems to me at the moment that it is saying that the area is a fixed constant $S > 0$, but then we are asked to maximize the area.... but it was assumed to be equal to $S$???

Comment: The area $S$ is fixed, yes. But since there are many functions satisfying the given conditions, we are looking for one that gives maximum $\tau$.

Comment: I see. I recommend piecewise linear functions. Piecewise linear functions are very useful in problems like these to "get a feel" for what is going on and let's you play around with the function. Just linear or exponential functions, like you tried, are too "rigid" to solve some of these problems, because you would like to make $f(\tau) = 0$, so you can try to "bend" the function, making it no longer differentiable, but still continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much, great insight. However, I think differentiability should also be a condition that I have overlooked!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac S \tau$. Clearly $S=\int_0^{\tau} f(x)dx \leq M \tau$ where $M$ is the supremum of f. So $M \geq \frac S \tau$. Now let $\epsilon >0$ and $f$ be the function with $f(0)=a,f(\tau)=0,f(x)=a_{\epsilon} \frac S \tau$ on $[\epsilon, \tau -\epsilon]$ and linear in $[0,\epsilon]$ as well as $[\tau -\epsilon, \tau]$. We can choose $a_{\epsilon}$ so that $\int_0^{\tau} f(x)dx=S$ As $\epsilon \to 0$ $a_\epsilon \to 1$ and the result follows from this. Note that the restrictions on $f(0)$ and $f(\tau)$ have no effect on the answer. I just noticed that you have imposed differentiability now, but the answer is the same since we can 'smoothly' join the graph on $[\epsilon, \tau -\epsilon]$ to the points $(0,a)$ and $(\tau ,0)$ and still choose $a_{\epsilon}$ to make teh integral $S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still do not see how $\frac{S}{\tau}$ is equal to $a$ in $f(0)$ or how exactly the mentioned 'smoothing' can be performed.

Comment: For smoothness you have to consider $\frac {a_\epsilon S} {\tau}+b(x-\epsilon)^{2}$ on $[0,\epsilon]$ where b is chosen such that $f(0)=a$ and a similar construction on $[\tau - \epsilon, \tau]$. Observe that at the point $\epsilon$ the left and right derivatives are both 0 so the function is differentiable.